# Write a block array of data to a file

Tags: rebol, rebol3

I'm stuck on this after many attempts, I have an array of items and I'm trying to output this to a file but the problem is that it writes all at once and ignores newline. I'm beginning to wonder if rebol even has such a simple ability. file1.txt contains multiple lines

```
myArray: []
foreach line read/lines %file1.txt [
    append myArray line
]
write %file2.txt myArray
```

this does not work, everything is written on to one line

```
fp: open/new %file2
foreach line myArray [insert fp line]
close fp
```

Neither does that work "cannot use insert on port!"

I am not trying to copy a file, The above is just a demonstration of what i'm trying to do.

Comment: In your second example you need to use `write` instead of `insert`.   So you could do `foreach line myArray [write fp join line newline]` or just `write/lines fp myArray`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rebol keeps newlines as they are. But after reading with read/lines you just get a block of items without the newlines. If you want a block of items written as lines separated by newlines, you should write them  again with the refinement write/lines and Rebol adds the newlines again.

```
myArray: []
foreach line read/lines %file1.txt [
    append myArray line
]
write/lines %file2.txt myArray
```

Comment: Additionally don't forget that you can SAVE your Rebol data and LOAD it back when necessary. SAVE also handles newlines if you say so with NEW-LINE function.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `read/lines` Rebol discards the line ending data and gives you an `block` of `strings`. If you want to write the `block` to a file you can add in the `newline` to each line.

```
myArray: []
foreach line read/lines %file1.txt [
    append myArray join line newline
}
write %file2.txt myArray
```

Comment: Looks like @sqllab has a cleaner answer using write/lines